# After button is clicked , another button won't click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a content slider just like youtube

[image]

And here is mine..

[image]

My content slides to right or left perfectly by 800px. But here's the problem.. When I click on the left icon first , Then clicking on the right icon won't work! Could there be a solution to this..?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#trendingnexticon").on('click' ,function(){
      $("#trendingtable").animate({right: '+=800px'});
    });
 });

 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#trendingpreviousicon").on('click' ,function(){
         $("#trendingtable").animate({left: '+=800px'});
     });
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="trendingdiv" class="" style="overflow-x:scroll; overflow: hidden;">
  <table id="trendingtable" class="table" style="position:relative;">
    <a id="trendingpreviousicon" style="cursor:pointer; margin-top: 62px; 
position:absolute; z-index:1;" class="previous round">&#8249;</a>
    <a id="trendingnexticon" style="cursor:pointer; margin-left: 1250px; 
margin-top: 62px; position:absolute; z-index:1;" class="next round">&#8250;
</a>
    <tr>
    <?php while ($tsingers = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tsingersquery)): ?>
      <td>
          <div class="media" style="border: 1px solid #e6e6e6; width:400px; 
padding: 0px;">
          <img src="images/<?=$tsingers['image'];?>" alt="<?
=$tsingers['name'];?>"
          class="pull-left img-responsive" style="width: 200px; height: 
150px;" id="artistimg">
          <div id="trendingmediabody" class="media-body">
            <p id="trendingname" style="font-size:14px; font-weight: 
bolder;"><?=$tsingers['name'];?></p>
            <p id="trendingcategory" style="font-size:12px; font-weight: 
bolder;"><?=$tsingers['category'];?></p></br></br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have two different `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: We'll need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here

Comment: Does your right icon works if you click first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "left" and "right" attributes are conflicting.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#trendingnexticon").on('click' ,function(){
      $("#trendingtable").animate({right: '+=800px'});
    });

     $("#trendingpreviousicon").on('click' ,function(){
         $("#trendingtable").animate({right: '-=800px'});
     });
 });
```

P.S.: I also removed the double $(document).ready since one is enough.

Comment: Yup , The 'Left' and 'Right' attributes were conflicting.. This works fine ~ .. Thanks bruv !

Comment: Also , Is there a way to fix the length of the div so it doesn't keep moving 800px to the left or to the right forever.. ? I tried giving it a fixed size in pixels and also tried "width: 100%" but both didn't work.. reallllllly sorry for being a newbie at this xD..

Comment: You need to calculate the total width  manually in JavaScript. Since I am currently on mobile I could check later how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, you only need one $(document).ready(), you can put both functions inside that one.

Try check on the inspector to see if after the slide animation something doesn't overlap the button

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess and say that it is because you are animating `left` and `right` instead of one or the other.  `left` doesn't mean "move left", it means, "set the `left` CSS style property".  And `left` means "where does my left border belong relative to my nearest relative parent".

Read a bit more about the [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) and [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) CSS properties.

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#trendingnexticon").on('click', function () {
        $("#trendingtable").animate({
            left: '-=800px'
        });
    });
    $("#trendingpreviousicon").on('click', function () {
        $("#trendingtable").animate({
            left: '+=800px'
        });
    });
});
```